# I can't add another row of buttons

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I want my fragment look like it has 3 buttons that fill the screen in both vertically and horizontally on the phone. I managed to do that somehow but I can't add another row of buttons. This is my layout... what am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll view contains only one direct child so you can not add second child directly you have to do following

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_weight="1">
     <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />


            </LinearLayout>
        <!--add here second row and other continue same -->

    </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTE**: If scrollview is only one element you going to use then you can make it root layout by removing current linearlayout from root and also remove scrollview weight for same case, it is good practice to minimize the layout hierarchy to performance improvement

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem but I have one more thing. I can't see the half of the buttons at the very bottom even though the scroll view works. It just does not go all the way down.

Comment: add android:fillViewport="true" in scrollview tag and check

Answer (score 0):

First Note  : scroll view remove effect of weight property 
Delete the scroll view element from your layout

Second note : each button make

```
<Button ...
 android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Because 0dp let the Android system calculate the height of button Equally